# the Mundus homonym, identical?

Tags: homonyms

Sometimes I run into Latin words that appear to be exact homonyms with no way to identify the word other than context. For example, the word mundus, when masculine, can seem to mean either clean (adjective) or the world/hell and there appears to be no way to tell which meaning is meant other than by context. Is that right?

It seems kind of odd that there would be the exact same word for two totally different meanings.

Comment: Homonyms exist in English too: "bark" is what trees have or what dogs do, a "bat" can fly or hit a ball, "mean" is either average or unkind, and many others.

Comment: I agree with the comment (which was automatically deleted by the system) that this is a duplicate, so I marked it as such. If you think it is not, please edit your question to elaborate on what you learned from that other question and what remains. Or if you want to focus on something different, perhaps asking a new separate question works better.